# Вставка строки в базу работает по разному в зависимости от способа вызова скрипта

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, apache, perl, utf-8

Я заметил, что перл вставляет в базу данных MSSQL неправильные кириличные строки будучи вызван через Апач. Платформа: Ubuntu server, Perl, Apache, mod-perl. Для тестов написал скрипт:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);

my $datasource = 'testsource';
my $cs = "dbi:ODBC:$datasource";
my $user = 'foo';
my $pwd = 'bar';

my $dbh = DBI->connect($cs, $user, $pwd, {RaiseError=>0,AutoCommit=>0})
or die "Database connection not made: " . DBI->errstr();

$dbh->{odbc_utf8_on}=1;
$dbh->{odbc_default_bind_type}=SQL_WVARCHAR;

my $tm = time;
my $sql = "insert into namevalue([Name], [ValueStr])values('sys_dbtest_$tm', N'проверка связи')";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->commit();
```

Поле в базе nvarchar. Когда я вызываю скрипт через Апач, в базу вставляются каракули: "Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐµÑÐºÐ° ÑÐ²ÑÐ·Ð¸"

Если запускать через терминал то вставка работает хорошо, строка коректная. Запускал через sudo, от имени своего юзера и от www-data: все работает отлично.

Перенес этот код в один из модулей сайта и вызвал, выполнив GET запрос к сайту, через Апач. Вставились каракули. Забрал вставку и заменил вызовом оригинального скрипта:

```
package UTF8test;

sub test {
  system('perl /home/Docia/uodbc.pl');
}

1;
```

Вызвал Апачем - каракули. Написал еще один скрипт:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/mysite';
use UTF8test;

UTF8test:test();
```

Вызвал это из терминала, получил правильный результат. По всему выходит что скрипт вставляет неправильные данные когда его вызывают через Апач. Не представляю в какую сторону тут копать: я не сильно админ, скорее програмист. Поставили передо мной задачу поднять тестовый сайт.

Помогите плиз!

Comment: Думаю что дравйвер ODBC чувствителен к системным настройка локали и под апачем они отличаются от системных. Для начала посмотрите переменную окружения LANG (`echo $LANG` в консоли). И попробуйте явно поставить такое же значение в начале скрипта `$ENV{LANG}="en_US.UTF-8"`. Кроме того я бы еще попробовал передавать данные в запрос как данные, а не писать в тексте, могут быть совершенно другие результаты. (`insert ... values(?,?) ... $sth->execute("sys_dbtest_$tm", 'Проверка связи');`) Собственно любые данные _всегда_ надо передавать через подстановку `?`

Comment: Не помогло. Ни ENV{LANG}, ни строки как данные. Результат полностью идентичен прошлым.

Comment: интересно что будет с данными, когда они придут от апача, т.е. скажем будут введены пользователем в форме. там результат может отличаться... А тип колонки какой ? там в описании DBD::ODBC написано что то про то, что данные должны передаваться в UTF-16 ...

Comment: Когда данные вводятся пользователем в форме, они становятся испорченными. И тут есть любопытный момент. Дело в том что мы сейчас мигрируем в Азуру вот и разворачиваем тестовый сайт для всесторонней проверки. Среди прочего скопировали базу. Так вот строки приехавшие с базой (нормальные) в браузере отображаются знаками вопроса. Сохраненные строки в базе каракулями, а в браузере - выглядят коректно. Тип колонки у нас nvarchar, а данные мы всегда передавали в раскодированном виде. Тобишь, функция encode и подобные никогда не юзались при вставке в базу или апдейте. Все работало.

Comment: Работали через тот же драйвер, т.е. через DBD::ODBC ? Что изменилось в среде, при переходе на азуру ? Если старые строки из БД в браузере не отображаются, то выходит есть более сложная проблема несоответствия кодировок. Что с этими же старыми строками в консоли (при запуске без апача)

Comment: И всё же, какая локаль активна при вызове с командной строки и из-под апача? LANG, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE? Вы сказали, что результат полностью идентичен, но не сказали, что́ же там имеется.

Comment: Mike: Изменилось очень многое. Новые версии драйверов, новая версия перла и базы данных. На то он и переезд!

Comment: Alexander Prokoshev: вы правы, тут есть несоответствие. Когда вызываю скрипт через терминал то результат такой: "LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=,LC_CTYPE=". Через Апач: "LANG=C,LC_ALL=,LC_CTYPE=". Однако если в начале скрипта просто написать "$ENV{LANG}='en_US.UTF-8'" то это никак не влияет на проблему запуска через Апач: каракули те-же самые. Возможно надо ставить как-то глобально на апач?

Comment: Проблема решена! Я изменил значение переменной LANG для апача в "/etc/apache2/envvars": export LANG=en_us.UTF-8
До этого значение переменной было С, и этого хватало для старого сервера. В новом что-то не срослось. Но теперь все отлично!